# PHP merge arrays with a condition

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I have 2 arrays. I would like to merge them into 1 array but with a condition. If Ref and Id are equal then merge

```
 Array Number One
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Id] => 60
        [Name] => Water Authority
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Id] => 63
        [Name] => Service Station 
    )

Array Number Two
 (
    [0] => Array
    (
        [Date] => 2017-10-12
        [Amount] => 130.00
        [Ref] => 60
        [Description] => Water Bill Oct
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Date] => 2017-10-10
        [Amount] => 130.00
        [Ref] => 63
        [Description] => Gas
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [Date] => 2017-09-17
        [Amount] => 600.00
        [Ref] => 60
        [Description] => Water bill Sept
    )
```

I would like to merge them with so I end up with:

```
    Merged Array
 (
    [0] => Array
    (
        [Date] => 2017-10-12
        [Amount] => 130.00
        [Ref] => 60
        [Description] => Water Bill Oct
        [Id] => 60
        [Name] => Water Authority
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Date] => 2017-10-10
        [Amount] => 130.00
        [Ref] => 63
        [Description] => Gas
        [Id] => 63
        [Name] => Service Station 
    )
   and so on...
```

How would I do that? I tried array_merge but I know it needs something else, just don't know what!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let assume first array be as $array1, second array be array2

$result = [];

```
foreach ($array1 as $key1 => $value1) {
    foreach ($array2 as $key2 => $value2) {
        if ($value1['Id']==$value2['Ref']) {
            $result[]=$value2+$value1;
        }
    }
}
```

The result will be as you expected

Comment: beware you of looping inside loops as it might greatly add to your algorithms complexity and reflect negativelly on performance