# Codeigniter - merge multiple associative array with condition

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, merge, associative-array

I need to merge multiple arrays into one where a specific key & its value are same. Here is the Sample_Array1

```
array(n) {
[0]=> array {
 ["a"]=> "m1"
 ["b"]=> "x2"
}
[1]=> array {
 ["a"]=> "n1"
 ["b"]=> "y2"
} ....
```

Sample_Array2 with one common key & other different ones.

```
array(n) {
[0]=> array {
 ["b"]=> "x2"
 ["c"]=> "p1"
}
[1]=> array {
 ["b"]=> "x2"
 ["d"]=> "q1"
}
[2]=> array {
 ["b"]=> "y2"
 ["e"]=> "r1"
} ....
```

Need to merge / append Sample_Array2 to Sample_Array1 where key-"b" & its value are same. The expected output:

```
array(n) {
[0]=>
array(2) {
 ["a"]=> "m1"
 ["b"]=> "x2"
 ["c"]=> "p1"
 ["d"]=> "q1"
}
[1]=>
array(2) {
 ["a"]=> "n1"
 ["b"]=> "y2"
 ["e"]=> "r1"
} ....
```

I have tried so many similar questions but couldn't find the exact result. 
[PHP merge arrays with a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46736541/php-merge-arrays-with-a-condition) The answer given on this link is not solving the purpose, its making different array for each new key, while I need to append the new keys in one array.

Comment: Make some foreach loops.

Comment: Is the "b" index present in all sub arrays?

Comment: @NeilPatrao yeah "b" would be common to match

Comment: Okay. Then my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47592845/1393400) should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, assuming you have the `"b"` index in all sub arrays.

```
$array1 = array();
$array1[] = array("a" => "m1", "b" => "x2", "c" => null);
$array1[] = array("a" => "n1", "b" => "y2");

$array2 = array();
$array2[] = array("b" => "x2", "c" => "p1");
$array2[] = array("a" => null, "b" => "x2", "d" => "q1");
$array2[] = array("b" => "y2", "e" => "r1");



function merge_on_key($array1, $array2, $key) {
    $result_array = array();
    foreach($array1 as $key1 => $sub_array1) {
        $merged_array = array();
        $sub_array1  = array_filter($sub_array1);
        foreach($array2 as $key2 => $sub_array2) {
            $sub_array2  = array_filter($sub_array2);
            if($sub_array1[$key] == $sub_array2[$key]) {
                $merged_array = array_merge($sub_array1, $sub_array2, $merged_array);
                unset($array2[$key2]);
            }
        }
        if (!empty($merged_array)) {
            $result_array[] = $merged_array;
        }
    }
    return array_merge($result_array, $array2);
}

$final_array = merge_on_key($array1, $array2, "b");

print_r($final_array);
```

In case you have to match the `"b"` index within the `$array1` itself too, then simply use it twice:

```
$array1 = merge_on_key($array1, $array1, "b");
$final_array = merge_on_key($array1, $array2, "b");
```

Comment: in this problem, is it possible to merge on non-empty values.. means if in two arrays few keys are same & one of its value is null, then keep the value which is not null.

Comment: You can filter the `sub_array`s for null values and then merge. Check the updated answer.

Comment: it is good, but its removing keys with null values also... 
`$array1 = array();
$array1[] = array("a" => "m1", "b" => "x2", "c" => null, "d" => "null");
$array2 = array();
$array2[] = array("a" => null, "b" => "x2", "c" => null, "d" => "q1");` 
need output as `array("a" => m1, "b" => "x2", "c" => null, "d" => "q1");`

Comment: here number of keys are same in all array segments. As this array will be exported as Excel sheet through codeigniter PHPExcel, so can't remove any key from any array.

Answer (score 0):

i really have no idea what you want to achieve here - but based on your description the following code works

```
$arrA = [
    0   =>
    [
        'a' => 'm1',
        'b' => 'x2'
    ],
    1   =>
    [
        'a' => 'n1',
        'b' => 'y2'
    ]
];

$arrB = [
    0 =>
    [
        'b' => 'x2',
        'c' => 'p1',
    ],
    1 =>
    [
        'b' => 'x2',
        'd' => 'q1',
    ],
    2 =>
    [
        'b' => 'y2',
        'e' => 'r1',
    ],
];

foreach($arrB AS $arrData)
{
    foreach($arrData AS $key => $val)
    {
        if ((isset($arrData['a']) && $arrData['a'] == $arrA[0]['a']) || (isset($arrData['b']) && $arrData['b'] == $arrA[0]['b']))
        {
            $arrA[0][$key] = $val;
        }
        elseif ((isset($arrData['b']) && $arrData['b'] == $arrA[1]['a']) || (isset($arrData['b']) && $arrData['b'] == $arrA[1]['b']))
        {
            $arrA[1][$key] = $val;
        }
    }
}

print_r($arrA);
```

Answer (score 0):

Created the arrays similar to yours. `$new_array` is the resultant array that you are looking for.

```
$a=array();

$a[0]=array('a'=>'m1', 'b'=>'x2');
$a[1]=array('a'=>'n1', 'b'=>'y2');

$b=array();
$b[0]=array('b'=>'x2', 'c'=>'p1');
$b[1]=array('b'=>'x2', 'd'=>'q1');
$b[2]=array('b'=>'y2', 'e'=>'r1');


foreach($a as $row){
    //echo '<pre>'; print_r($row);
    foreach($b as $c=>$row1){
        //echo '<pre>'; print_r($row1);echo $c;die;
    if($row['b']==$row1['b']){
        $new_array[]=array_merge($row, $row1);

    }
    }

}echo '<pre>'; print_r($new_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Gather all values of b from both arrays
$all_b = array_unique(array_merge(array_column($arr1, 'b'), array_column($arr2, 'b')));

$res = [];

// For each b value
foreach($all_b as $b) {
     $temp = [];
     // Scan the arrays for items with the same b value
     foreach($arr1 as $a1) {
        if ($a1['b'] == $b) $temp = array_merge($temp, $a1);
     }
     foreach($arr2 as $a2) {
        if ($a2['b'] == $b) $temp = array_merge($temp, $a2);
     }
     // Save them to new array
     $res[] = $temp; 
}

print_r($res);
```

[**demo on eval**](https://eval.in/911402)